# My Highchart graphs are really slow when I choose 30 day graphs

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a graph page with multiple datapoints on t with HighCharts but I am having a really hard time being able to pull the 24 hour or 30 day charts.  It loads way too slowly.  I've been through the documents that talk about performance, but am having a hard time figuring it out so I thought I would post something online.

Here is an example of my code:

`` series: [{
    name: 'tmp_name',
    pointStart: 1384325437000,
    pointInterval: 300000
    },{
        data: [ [1384325400000,14340],[1384325460000,14340],[1384325520000,14340],`[1384325580000,14340],[1384325640000,14340],[1384325700000,14340],[1384325760000,14340],[1384325820000,14340],[1384325880000,14340],[1384325940000,14340],[1384326000000,14340],[1384326060000,14340],[1384326120000,14340],[1384326180000,14340],[1384326240000,14340],[1384326300000,14340],[1384326360000,14340],[1384326420000,14340],[1384326480000,14340],[1384326540000,14340],[1384326600000,14340],[1384326660000,14340],[1384326720000,14340],[1384326780000,14340],[1384326840000,14340],[1384326900000,14340],[1384326960000,14340],[1384327020000,14340],[1384327080000,14340],[1384327140000,14340],[1384327200000,14340],[1384327260000,14340],[1384327320000,14340],[1384327380000,14340],[1384327440000,14340],[1384327500000,14340],[1384327560000,14340],[1384327620000,14340],[1384327680000,14340],[1384327740000,14340],[1384327800000,14340],[1384327860000,14340],[1384327920000,14340],[1384327980000,14340],[1384328040000,14340],[1384328100000,14340],[1384328160000,14340],[1384328220000,14340],[1384328280000,14340],[1384328340000,14340],[1384328400000,14340],[1384328460000,14340],[1384328520000,14340],[1384328580000,14340],[1384328640000,14340],[1384328700000,14340],[1384328760000,14340],[1384328820000,14340],[1384328880000,14340],[1384328940000,14340],[1384329000000,14340],[1384329060000,14340],[1384329120000,14340],[1384329180000,14340],[1384329240000,14340],[1384329300000,14340],[1384329360000,14340],[1384329420000,14340],[1384329480000,14340],[1384329540000,14340],[1384329600000,14340],[1384329660000,14340],[1384329720000,14340],[1384329780000,14340],[1384329840000,14340],[1384329900000,14340],[1384329960000,14340],[1384330020000,14340],[1384330080000,14340],[1384330140000,14340],[1384330200000,14340],[1384330260000,14340],[1384330320000,14340],[1384330380000,14340],[1384330440000,14340],[1384330500000,14340],[1384330560000,14340],[1384330620000,14340],[1384330680000,14340],[1384330740000,14340],[1384330800000,14340],[1384330860000,14340],[1384330920000,14340],[1384330980000,14340],[1384331040000,14340],[1384331100000,14340],[1384331160000,14340],[1384331220000,14340],[1384331280000,14340],[1384331340000,14340],[1384331400000,14340],[1384331460000,14340],[1384331520000,14340],[1384331580000,14340],[1384331640000,14340],[1384331700000,14340],[1384331760000,14340],[1384331820000,14340],[1384331880000,14340],[1384331940000,14340],[1384332000000,14340],[1384332060000,14340],[1384332120000,14340],[1384332180000,14340],[1384332240000,14340],[1384332300000,14340],[1384332360000,14340],[1384332420000,14340],[1384332480000,14340],[1384332540000,14340],[1384332600000,14340],[1384332660000,14340],[1384332720000,14340],[1384332780000,14340],[1384332840000,14340],[1384332900000,14340],[1384332960000,14340],[1384333020000,14340],[1384333080000,14340],[1384333140000,14340],[1384333200000,14340],[1384333260000,14340],[1384333320000,14340],[1384333380000,14340],[1384333440000,14340],[1384333500000,14340],[1384333560000,14340],[1384333620000,14340],[1384333680000,14340],[1384333740000,14340],[1384333800000,14340],[1384333860000,14340],[1384333920000,14340],[1384333980000,14340],[1384334040000,14340],[1384334100000,14340],[1384334160000,14340],[1384334220000,14340],[1384334280000,14340],[1384334340000,14340],[1384334400000,14340],[1384334460000,14340],[1384334520000,14340],[1384334580000,14340],[1384334640000,14340],[1384334700000,14340],[1384334760000,14340],[1384334820000,14340],[1384334880000,14340],[1384334940000,14340],[1384335000000,14340],[1384335060000,14340],[1384335120000,14340],[1384335180000,14340],[1384335240000,14340],[1384335300000,14340],[1384335360000,14340],[1384335420000,14340],[1384335480000,14340],[1384335540000,14340],[1384335600000,14340],[1384335660000,14340],[1384335720000,14340],[1384335780000,14340],[1384335840000,14340],[1384335900000,14340],[1384335960000,14340],[1384336020000,14340],[1384336080000,14340],[1384336140000,14340],[1384336200000,14340],[1384336260000,14340],[1384336320000,14340],[1384336380000,14340],[1384336440000,14340],[1384336500000,14340],[1384336560000,14340],[1384336620000,14340],[1384336680000,14340],[1384336740000,14340],[1384336800000,14340],[1384336860000,14340],[1384336920000,14340],[1384336980000,14340],[1384337040000,14340],[1384337100000,14340],[1384337160000,14340],[1384337220000,14340],[1384337280000,14340],[1384337340000,14340],[1384337400000,14340],[1384337460000,14340],[1384337520000,14340],[1384337580000,14340],[1384337640000,14340],[1384337700000,14340],[1384337760000,14340],[1384337820000,14340],[1384337880000,14340],[1384337940000,14340],[1384338000000,14340],[1384338060000,14340],[1384338120000,14340],[1384338180000,14340],[1384338240000,14340],[1384338300000,14340],[1384338360000,14340],[1384338420000,14340],[1384338480000,14340],[1384338540000,14340],[1384338600000,14340],[1384338660000,14340],[1384338720000,14340],[1384338780000,14340],[1384338840000,14340],[1384338900000,14340],[1384338960000,14...,[1384398180000,14340],[1384398240000,14340],[1384398300000,14340],[1384398360000,14340],[1384398420000,14340],[1384398480000,14340],[1384398540000,14340],[1384398600000,14340],[1384398660000,14340],[1384398720000,14340],[1384398780000,14340],[1384398840000,14340],[1384398900000,14340],[1384398960000,14340],[1384399020000,14340],[1384399080000,14340],[1384399140000,14340],[1384399200000,14340],[1384399260000,14340],[1384399320000,14340],[1384399380000,14340],[1384399440000,14340],[1384399500000,14340],[1384399560000,14340],[1384399620000,14340],[1384399680000,14340],[1384399740000,14340],[1384399800000,14340],[1384399860000,14340],[1384399920000,14340],[1384399980000,14340],[1384400040000,14340],[1384400100000,14340],[1384400160000,14340],[1384400220000,14340],[1384400280000,14340],[1384400340000,14340],[1384400400000,14340],[1384400460000,14340],[1384400520000,14340],[1384400580000,14340],[1384400640000,14340],[1384400700000,14340],[1384400760000,14340],[1384400820000,14340],[1384400880000,14340],[1384400940000,14340],[1384401000000,14340],[1384401060000,14340],[1384401120000,14340],[1384401180000,14340],[1384401240000,14340],[1384401300000,14340],[1384401360000,14340],[1384401420000,14340],[1384401480000,14340],[1384401540000,14340],[1384401600000,14340],[1384401660000,14340],[1384401720000,14340],[1384401780000,14340],[1384401840000,14340],[1384401900000,14340],[1384401960000,14340],[1384402020000,14340],[1384402080000,14340],[1384402140000,14340],[1384402200000,14340],[1384402260000,14340],[1384402320000,14340],[1384402380000,14340],[1384402440000,14340],[1384402500000,14340],[1384402560000,14340],[1384402620000,14340],[1384402680000,14340],[1384402740000,14340],[1384402800000,14340],[1384402860000,14340],[1384402920000,14340],[1384402980000,14340],[1384403040000,14340],[1384403100000,14340],[1384403160000,14340],[1384403220000,14340],[1384403280000,14340],[1384403340000,14340],[1384403400000,14340],[1384403460000,14340],[1384403520000,14340],[1384403580000,14340],[1384403640000,14340],[1384403700000,14340],[1384403760000,14340],[1384403820000,14340],[1384403880000,14340],[1384403940000,14340],[1384404000000,14340],[1384404060000,14340],[1384404120000,14340],[1384404180000,14340],[1384404240000,14340],[1384404300000,14340],[1384404360000,14340],[1384404420000,14340],[1384404480000,14340],[1384404540000,14340],[1384404600000,14340],[1384404660000,14340],[1384404720000,14340],[1384404780000,14340],[1384404840000,14340],[1384404900000,14340],[1384404960000,14340],[1384405020000,14340],[1384405080000,14340],[1384405140000,14340],[1384405200000,14340],[1384405260000,14340],[1384405320000,14340],[1384405380000,14340],[1384405440000,14340],[1384405500000,14340],[1384405560000,14340],[1384405620000,14340],[1384405680000,14340],[1384405740000,14340],[1384405800000,14340],[1384405860000,14340],[1384405920000,14340],[1384405980000,14340],[1384406040000,14340],[1384406100000,14340],[1384406160000,14340],[1384406220000,14340],[1384406280000,14340],[1384406340000,14340],[1384406400000,14340],[1384406460000,14340],[1384406520000,14340],[1384406580000,14340],[1384406640000,14340],[1384406700000,14340],[1384406760000,14340],[1384406820000,14340],[1384406880000,14340],[1384406940000,14340],[1384407000000,14340],[1384407060000,14340],[1384407120000,14340],[1384407180000,14340],[1384407240000,14340],[1384407300000,14340],[1384407360000,14340],[1384407420000,14340],[1384407480000,14340],[1384407540000,14340],[1384407600000,14340],[1384407660000,14340],[1384407720000,14340],[1384407780000,14340],[1384407840000,14340],[1384407900000,14340],[1384407960000,14340],[1384408020000,14340],[1384408080000,14340],[1384408140000,14340],[1384408200000,14340],[1384408260000,14340],[1384408320000,14340],[1384408380000,14340],[1384408440000,14340],[1384408500000,14340],[1384408560000,14340],[1384408620000,14340],[1384408680000,14340],[1384408740000,14340],[1384408800000,14340],[1384408860000,14340],[1384408920000,14340],[1384408980000,14340],[1384409040000,14340],[1384409100000,14340],[1384409160000,14340],[1384409220000,14340],[1384409280000,14340],[1384409340000,14340],[1384409400000,14340],[1384409460000,14340],[1384409520000,14340],[1384409580000,14340],[1384409640000,14340],[1384409700000,14340],[1384409760000,14340],[1384409820000,14340],[1384409880000,14340],[1384409940000,14340],[1384410000000,14340],[1384410060000,14340],[1384410120000,14340],[1384410180000,14340],[1384410240000,14340],[1384410300000,14340],[1384410360000,14340],[1384410420000,14340],[1384410480000,14340],[1384410540000,14340],[1384410600000,14340],[1384410660000,14340],[1384410720000,14340],[1384410780000,14340],[1384410840000,14340],[1384410900000,14340],[1384410960000,14340],[1384411020000,14340],[1384411080000,14340],[1384411140000,14340],[1384411200000,14340],[1384411260000,14340],[1384411320000,14340],[1384411380000,14340],[1384411440000,14340],[1384411500000,14340],[1384411560000,14340],[1384411620000,14340],[1384411680000,14340],[1384411740000,14340] ],
    ]; ``

Here is an example of my jfiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/niebais/zN33X/1/

What am I doing wrong to load this data?  How can I speed this up?  It's almost unusable if I use anything over 4 hours.

Comment: did you try hard code these data to javascript highchart?? If problem solved, means this JSON created by json_encode took too much time. Then it is not the high chart problem but web server.

Comment: I put a fiddle example to take a look at.  The page loads REALLY slowly (if at all).  Those values are already hardcoded into the sample code I sent.  I am running multiple datasources at the same time.  Here is the jfiddle link again: http://jsfiddle.net/niebais/zN33X/1/

Comment: Please check the correctness of series data. Some data seems corrupted: `[...00,0]`, `[138434124000...84395000000,0]`, etc

Answer (score 0):

That fiddle won't load properly for me, but one thing you can try is to make sure animation is disabled, as animation can make a big difference in rendering time for larger charts.

```
    chart: {
        animation: false
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable animations / shadows / markers. In other cases I advice to use highstock with enabled dataGrouping.